# Sencha Touch 1 scrollTo not working

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch

I have a sencha touch panel with a large html document loaded inside as html property. This html comes from external system so I can change it. It contains some jump to anchors. So when user click on this links i need so scroll my panel to some anchor further in the html.
I use this code for scrolling:

```
scrollDocumentToAnchor = function (id) {
            var el = Ext.get(id);            
            me.scroller.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: el.getOffsetsTo(me.scrollEl)[1] }, true);
};
```

but it doesn't work. I know it's now easy to say without the full example, but maybe anyone had similar issues in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide us the code of the `me` variable.

Did you try a simple `scroller.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0 });`

Are you sure `el.getOffsetsTo(me.scrollEl)[1]` returns something ?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I tried to hardcode these values but with no success.